# Sum probability

Tags: diffie-hellman, group-theory

if $a,b,c$ are selected at random from a large cyclic group, then what could be the probability that 
$g^{a+b}$=$g^c$?
it simply corresponds to  the probability that multiplication of two random numbers A and B in group G equals to a given random number C in G

Comment: Theorem: let $g$ be an element of a finite group $G$, and $a, b$ be integers. Then $g^a = g^b$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are congruent modulo the order of $g$.

Comment: Since this looks a bit like homework or an assignment — what have you tried and/or what research have you done?

Comment: By the way, the fact that you say that "a,b,c are selected at random from a large cyclic group" may indicate a misunderstanding. In order for exponentiation to make sense; they must be ether "plain" integers, or integers modulo the order of $g$ (or at the very least a multiple thereof, such as the order of $G$). They can't be elements of just any group; what sense would it make if exponents were elliptic curve points, for example?

Comment: You are right, I meant $a$,$b$ and $c$ are random plain integers

Comment: The result should actually be $0$ because, this is (basically) the same question as: What is the probabiltity that two random integers are equal (note that a random integer added with a random integer is another random integer). Also note that we can't sample uniformly at random from an infinite set (because then every number would have probability $0$ of being picked).

Comment: What exactly is the space $a$, $b$, and $c$ are drawn from?  $\mathbb{Z}$?  $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, where $n = \operatorname{ord}(g)$?  $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ where $n \mid m$?  $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ where $n \nmid m$?  What exactly is the distribution on the space, and the map from the space to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as exponents of $g$?  If the space is really $\mathbb{Z}$, then since $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite the distribution can't be uniform as everyone would assume for the finite space $\mathbb{Z}/n^k\mathbb{Z}$, so you'll have to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the first comment, $g^{a+b}=g^c$ if and only if $a+b$ is congruent to $c$ modulo $Order(g).$

Assuming $a,b$ are chosen at random from $G$, $g^{a+b}$ is uniformly distributed in $G$.

Since $Order(g)$ divides $|G|$,  $g^{a+b}$ is uniformly distributed in the equivalence classes that the distinct powers of $g$ induce. Now the uniformity gives that the probability that $$g^{a+b}=g^c$$ for any fixed $c$ is exactly $$\frac{1}{Order(g)}.$$ Of course if $g$ is a generator then $Order(g)=|G|.$

Comment: shouldn't the birthday paradox also play into the probability, after all we are only interested in any such triple without any fixed constant in it?

Comment: Birthday paradox would apply, for example, to a set of exponents: how many exponents must you have before some subset of three of them satisfies this condition?  The question as asked appears to be of the probability that some triple $(a, b, c)$ drawn from some distribution on some space satisfies the condition.  If drawn uniformly from $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n = \operatorname{ord}(g)$, then there are clearly $n^3$ possible triples, and since for each $(a, b)$ there is a unique $c$ with $a+b \equiv c \pmod n$, there are $n^2$ satisfying the condition, hence probability $n^2/n^3 = 1/n$.